# SSMS Check Constraint Does not Allow Update of Table with valid data

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints, ssms-2014

I have the following in my table design from the Script Table as...Create To...New Query Window of SSMS:

```
CREATE TABLE [DirectMarketing].[Opportunity](
    [OpportunityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProspectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateRaised] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Likelihood] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Rating] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [EstimatedClosingDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EstimatedRevenue] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [DirectMarketing].[Opportunity] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Opportunity_DateRaised]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateRaised]
GO

ALTER TABLE [DirectMarketing].[Opportunity]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Opportunity] CHECK  (([DateRaised]=getdate()))
GO

ALTER TABLE [DirectMarketing].[Opportunity] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Opportunity]
GO
```

But when I try to test it by entering data into the table i keep getting an error saying no row was update. Kindly see the image below for data entered and subsequent error. **What am I not doing right?**

[image]

Comment: `GetDate()` returns a `DateTime`, I've never tried to use a constraint like that before but I'm guessing you're running into an issue comparing a `Date` to a `DateTime`. You could try converting to `Date` first, but I think you might still have a race condition around midnight each day.

Comment: What's `CK_Opportunity` supposed to achieve? You essentially have mandated that all rows must always have the current date/time in the column `DateRaised` at all times -- a constraint that is impossible to meet, and that would be so even if you changed the actual type to `DateTime`. `CHECK` constraints must logically hold at every time, not merely when rows change; if you break that rule, you'll get unintuitive problems.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller I suspect that would be the problem, but it does happen even if the DateRaised is data typed as datetime.

Comment: That's because when you add time, whatever you type in won't match the system time. I tested with a `CAST` and it works but it's still a very strange requirement. What are you actually trying to do? Your default value will ensure it gets set if someone doesn't pass a value for an `INSERT`, if you're worried about somebody passing an old date a `TRIGGER` might be a better solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert CK_Opportunity is supposed to check that the date entered in DateRaised is today's date. For all rows having the current date/time factor, I want to believe the WITH NOCHECK should not check for old data that has already past the date entered for them.

How do i use the TRIGGER?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller How did you do the CASTing? On the Default or the Constraint itself?

Comment: The constraint will still apply to all data in the future, including existing rows that are modified. Rows you add today will become logically invalid tomorrow. You can "get away with this" if you promise to never update any rows, never run an `ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT` and never make a copy of this table, but it's a time bomb waiting to go off. `CHECK` constraints are there to hold "always", not merely on inserting.

Comment: On the constraint, just like Dan's answer `([DateRaised]=CAST(getdate() AS DATE))`

Comment: If the check is supposed to hold only on insert (and you don't care about existing rows) an `AFTER INSERT` trigger would do (`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE DateRaised <> CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) RAISERROR(...)`). If you additionally want to check things like the date not ever being modified after inserting (not even to today's date, which this check would allow) an `AFTER UPDATE` is necessary.

Comment: `it does happen even if the DateRaised is data typed as datetime` -- this is because getDate() returns the current time. So when the row is create, the field is set to the current time... as the rest of the fields are added, time passes. When it is saved, time has passed, let's say four seconds, so then constraint is checked again, using getDate(), well, the current time is no longer what it was when getDate() was called for the default value, so tehy no longer match, the constraint fails.

Comment: I get what you all are saying and I have rectified [temporarily] with the CASTing. But don't you think the "Check Existing Data on Creation or Re-Enabling?" on SSMS which I set to NO can solve this problem of future update or check constraint?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Can you help me with a TRIGGER code/syntax you talked about?

Comment: What are your requirements? If somebody tries to update a row do you want `DateRaised` changed to todays date? Do you want an error to be thrown? How about an insert? Do you want it to silently change the provided value to today's date,  or do you want it to throw an error?

Comment: If I am looking at a kind of Serice Request Creation and since, DateRaised would default to (& the Constraint would ensure that only) today's (is entered), then it should not update silently. It should only throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `[DateRaised]=GETDATE()` is comparing types of `date` and `datetime`. Because `datetime` has a higher precedence, the date value is converted to a datetime with a time of midnight. The comparison then returns false because of the non-midnight time.

The solution is to add a `CAST`:

```
ALTER TABLE [DirectMarketing].[Opportunity] 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Opportunity] CHECK ([DateRaised]=CAST(getdate() AS date));
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the essential problem with this constraint, which is that it will implicitly render the table inconsistent as time progresses (as time is wont to do). Dynamic conditions should be checked with triggers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the check constraint will of course only evaluate the value at the time of entry. I assumed that is the purpose of the constraint.

Comment: The constraint will evaluate whenever evaluated. In particular, something like `UPDATE Opportunity SET DateRaised = DateRaised` will fail tomorrow, and of course anyone foolish enough to do an `ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT` will find out that the constraint is not supposed to ever be re-evaluated... I have seen this blow up enough times that I don't consider the "of course" to be obvious anymore. I dislike triggers as much as the next person, but I like half-evaluated constraints even less.

Comment: I have used the CASTing and it did work, but I guess I may have to play with the TRIGGER if it will solve the problem.
@DanGuzman That is supposed to be the purpose of the entry.

Comment: @HCM, if `DateRaised` is not subsequently updated, the check constraint will be evaluated only during inserts. If the value is updated, the new value will be evaluated against the check constraint and will fail if the new date is not today.